# Istio virtual service spec host and destination rule host

Tags: istio

I'm trying to understand `Istio` configuration model but the more I read the more I get confused, especially around the `hosts` and `host` fields. In their examples, they all use the same short name and I'm not sure whether they mean the virtual service name, the `Kubernetes` service hostname or the `dns` service address.

Assuming I have the following configuration:

- My Kubernetees project namespace is called `poc-my-ns`
- Inside `poc-my-ns` I have my pods (both version 1 and 2) a `Kubernetes` route and a `Kubernetes` service.
- The service hostname is: `poc-my-ns.svc.cluster.local` and the route is `https://poc-my-ns.orgdevcloudapps911.myorg.org`.
- Everything is up and running and the service selector gets all pods from all versions as it should. (`Istio` virtual service suppose to do the final selection by version).

The intended `Istio` configuration looks like that:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: poc-my-dr
spec:
  host: poc-my-ns.svc.cluster.local # ???
  subsets:
    - name: v1
      labels:
        version: 1.0
    - name: v2
      labels:
        version: 2.0
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: poc-my-vs
spec:
  hosts:
    - poc-my-ns.svc.cluster.local # ???
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: poc-my-dr # ???
            subset: v1
          weight: 70
        - destination:
            host: poc-my-dr # ???
            subset: v2
          weight: 30
```

My questions are:

1. Is the destination rule `spec/host` refers to the `Kubernetes` service hostname?
2. Is the virtual service `spec/hosts` refers to the `Kubernetes` service hostname, Is it the route `https://poc-my-ns.orgdevcloudapps911.myorg.org` or something else?
3. Is the virtual service `spec/http/route/destination/host` refers to the destination rule name or does it suppose to point to the `Kubernetes` service hostname or should it be the virtual service `metadata/name`?

I will really appreciate clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VirtualService` and `DestinationRule` basically configure the envoy-proxy of the istio mesh. The `VirtualService` defines where to route the traffic to and the `DestinationRule` defines what to additionally do with the traffic.

For the VS the `spec.hosts` list can contain kubernetes internal and external hosts.

Say you want the define how to route traffic for `api.example.com` coming from outside the kubernetes cluster through the istio-ingressgateway `my-gateway` into the mesh. It should be routed to the `rating` app in the `store` namespace, so the VS would look like this:

```yaml
spec:
  hosts:
  - api.example.com # external host
  gateway:
  - my-gateway # the ingress-gateway
  http:
  - [...]
    route:
    - destination:
      host: rating.store.svc.cluster.local # kubernetes service
```

If you want to define how cluster/mesh internal traffic is routed, you set `rating.store.svc.cluster.local` in the `spec.hosts` list and define the `mesh` gateway (or leave it out like you did, because `mesh` is the default) and route it to the `rating.store.svc.cluster.local` service. You also add a DR where you define subsets and route all mesh internal traffic to subset `v1`.

```yaml
# VS
[...]
spec:
  hosts:
  - rating.store.svc.cluster.local # cluster internal host
  gateway:
  - mesh # mesh internal gateway (default when omitted)
  http:
  - [...]
    route:
    - destination:
        host: rating.store.svc.cluster.local # cluster internal host
        subset: v1 # defined in destinationrule below
---
[...]
spec:
  host: rating.store.svc.cluster.local # cluster internal host
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      version: v1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      version: v2
```

But it could also be that you want to route traffic to a cluster external destination. In that case `destination.host` would be an external fqdn, like in this example from docs:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-svc-wikipedia
spec:
  hosts:
  - wikipedia.org
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: example-http
    protocol: HTTP
  resolution: DNS
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-wiki-rule
spec:
  hosts:
  - wikipedia.org
  http:
  - timeout: 5s
    route:
    - destination:
        host: wikipedia.org
```

Think about it as "I want to route traffic from HOST_FROM to HOST_TO", where

- HOST_FROM is `spec.host` and `spec.hosts`
- HOST_TO is `destination.host`

and both can be inside the kubernetes cluster or outside.

So to answer all your questions:

It depends: If you want to route from/to cluster internal traffic you'll use a kubernetes service fqdn. For cluster external traffic you'll use the external target fqdn.

I highly recommend reading through the docs of [VirtualService](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service) and [DestinationRule](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/) where you can see several examples with explanations.